# Ошибка при запросе API Kuna

Tags: php, api, guzzle

Не получается выполнить запрос, выдает ошибку `{"messages":["the_tonce_is_invalid"]}`

Ошибка связана с меткой времени, но никак не получается ее побороть. Может есть идеи?

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;


$public_key = '';
$secret_key = '';


$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.kuna.io',
]);

// $api_path = '/v3/auth/kuna_codes/issued-by-me';
$api_path = '/v3/auth/me';
$nonce = strval(date_timestamp_get(date_create()));
// $nonce = time();
$data = (object) [];

$headers = [
    // 'accept' => 'application/json',
    // 'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'kun-nonce' => $nonce,
    'kun-apikey' => $public_key,
    'kun-signature' => hash_hmac('sha384', $api_path.$nonce.json_encode($data), $secret_key),
];
$options = [
    'form_params' => $data,
    'headers' => $headers,
    'http_errors' => false,
    // 'debug' => true,
];

print_r($options);
// var_dump($options);

$response = $client->request('POST', $api_path, $options);
$result = $response->getBody()->getContents();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: попробуйте пример из [afanasiev.top/kuna-api-v3-primer-zaprosa](https://afanasiev.top/blog/posts/kuna-api-v3-primer-zaprosa)

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://docs.kuna.io/docs/api-data-schema-and-serialization#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> kun-nonce - Метка времени запроса. Указывается в формате Unix Time Stamp в **милисекундах** (ms).

Ошибка в документации(отписал в саппорт), в php примере, на этой строке:

```
$nonce = strval(date_timestamp_get(date_create()));
```

date_timestamp_get - возвращает временную метку Unix, **секунды**.

Как вариант, миллисекунды можно получить вот так:

```
$nonce = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```